# Web scraping using rvest works partially ok

Tags: r, rvest

I'm new into web scraping using rvest in R and I'm trying to access to the left column match names of this betting house using xpath. So i know the names are under the  tag. But i cant access to them using the next code:

```
html="https://www.supermatch.com.uy/live#/5009370062"
a=read_html(html)
a %>% html_nodes(xpath="//span") %>% html_text()
```

But i only access to some of the text. I was reading that this may be because the website dynamically pull data from databases using JavaScript and jQuery. Do you know how i can access to these match names? Already thank you guys.

Comment: Which text are you trying to get?

Comment: Try with `https://www.supermatch.com.uy/live_recargar_menu/`

Comment: Thanks margusl!! that seems to work. Can i ask how you achieve it?

Comment: I am trying to get the names of the matches @TomHoel

Comment: @EmilianoBarone , collected few pointers into answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Some generic notes about basic scraping strategies

Following refers to Google Chrome and Chrome DevTools, but those same concepts apply to other browsers and built-in developer tools too. One thing to remember about *rvest* is that it can only handle response delivered for that specific request, i.e. content that is **not** fetched / transformed / generated by JavasScript running on the client side.

- Loading the page and inspecting elements to extract xpath or css selector for *rvest* seems to be most most common approach. Though the static content behind that URL versus the rendered page in browser and elemts in inspector can be quite different. To take some guesswork out of the process, it's better to start by checking what is the actual content that *rvest* might receive - open the page source and skim through it or just search for a term you are interested in. At the time of writing *Viettel* is playing, but they are not listed anywhere in the source:
  [image: search 1]
  Meaning there's no reason to expect that *rvest* would be able to extract that data.
- You could also disable JavaScript for that particular site in your browser and check if that particular piece of information is still there. If not, it's not there for *rvest* either.
- If you want to step further and/or suspect that *rvest* receives something different compared to your browser session (target site is checking request headers and delivers some anti-scraping notice when it doesn't like the *user-agent*, for example), you can always check the **actual** content *rvest* was able to retrieve, for example `read_html(some_url) %>% as.character()` to dump the whole response, `read_html(some_url) %>% xml2::html_structure()` to get formatted stucture of the page or `read_html(some_url) %>% xml2::write_html("temp.html")` to save the page content and inspect it in editor or browser.
- Coming back to Supermatch & DevTools. That data on a left pane must be coming from somewhere. What usually works is a search on the network pane - open network, clear current content, refresh the page and make sure page is fully loaded; run a search (for "Viettel" for example):
  [image: search 2]
  And you'll have the URL from there. There are some IDs in that request (`https://www.supermatch.com.uy/live_recargar_menu/32512079?_=1656070333214`) and it's wise to assume those values might be related to current session or are just shortlived. So sometimes it's worth trying what would happen if we just clean it up a bit, i.e. remove `32512079?_=1656070333214`. In this case it happens to work.
- While here it's just a fragment of *html* and it makes sense to parse it with *rvest* , in most cases you'll end up landing on JSON and the process transforms into working with APIs. When it happens it's time to switch from *rvest* to something more apropriate for JSON, *jsonlite* + *httr* for example.
- Sometimes plane *rvest* is not enough and you either want or need to work with the page as it would have been rendered in your JavaScript-enabled browser. For this there's *RSelenium*

Comment: margusl Thank you so much for the time that you dedicated to this, the notes are really clear and helped me a lot! Also motivated me to learn how to use RSelenium.