# Webscraping NBA.com

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to webscrape the following table using R

https://www.nba.com/stats/teams/opponent-shooting

The code I have written is as follows

```
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.nba.com/stats/teams/opponent-shooting"

page <- read_html(url)

table_data <- page %>% 
  html_table(fill=TRUE)
```

However this appears to return a table of what looks to be a calendar month.

Any idea how to successfully webscrape the intended table please?

Comment: What data do you actually want from the landing page? There are plenty of tools you could use. I'm not familiar with how R does it but I've got plenty of experience with tools in Java like JSoup/HtmlUnit that you could use to output a file (.csv). Then you could process that

Comment: That page didn’t seem to have stats in a table. Perhaps find an URL that brings up a specific table https://www.nba.com/stats/teams/traditional OR https://www.nba.com/stats/teams/clutch-traditional

Comment: @RobEvans JSoup is equivalent to what OP is already doing (specifically, of the ‘rvest’ R package). HtmlUnit is usable directly in R via Selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments it seems the page might be displayed differently for some, for reference, this is how it renders for me - https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLZ7.png

Anyway, it's a dynamic JavaScript-driven page and the table content (JSON) is fetched through an API call. Which you can trace down through the network tab of your browser's developer tools. To make that request yourself (and succeed), you'd need to alter request headers a bit; here's one option on how this might look with `httr2`:

```r
library(httr2)

req_url <- "https://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashteamshotlocations?Conference=&DateFrom=&DateTo=&DistanceRange=5ft%20Range&Division=&GameScope=&GameSegment=&ISTRound=&LastNGames=0&Location=&MeasureType=Opponent&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PORound=0&PaceAdjust=N&PerMode=PerGame&Period=0&PlayerExperience=&PlayerPosition=&PlusMinus=N&Rank=N&Season=2023-24&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular%20Season&ShotClockRange=&StarterBench=&TeamID=0&VsConference=&VsDivision="

json <- 
  request(req_url) |>
  req_user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36") |>
  req_headers(
    Accept = "*/*",
    Origin = "https://www.nba.com",
    Referer = "https://www.nba.com/",
  ) |> 
  req_perform() |>
  resp_body_json() 

hdr <- json$resultSets$headers

# build column names from 2-level header structure
clean_names <- 
  c(
    rep("", hdr[[1]]$columnsToSkip), 
    rep(unlist(hdr[[1]]$columnNames), each = 3)
    ) |>
  paste(unlist(hdr[[2]]$columnNames)) |>
  janitor::make_clean_names()
clean_names
#>  [1] "team_id"                   "team_name"                
#>  [3] "less_than_5_ft_opp_fgm"    "less_than_5_ft_opp_fga"   
#>  [5] "less_than_5_ft_opp_fg_pct" "x5_9_ft_opp_fgm"          
#>  [7] "x5_9_ft_opp_fga"           "x5_9_ft_opp_fg_pct"       
#>  [9] "x10_14_ft_opp_fgm"         "x10_14_ft_opp_fga"        
#> [11] "x10_14_ft_opp_fg_pct"      "x15_19_ft_opp_fgm"        
#> [13] "x15_19_ft_opp_fga"         "x15_19_ft_opp_fg_pct"     
#> [15] "x20_24_ft_opp_fgm"         "x20_24_ft_opp_fga"        
#> [17] "x20_24_ft_opp_fg_pct"      "x25_29_ft_opp_fgm"        
#> [19] "x25_29_ft_opp_fga"         "x25_29_ft_opp_fg_pct"     
#> [21] "x30_34_ft_opp_fgm"         "x30_34_ft_opp_fga"        
#> [23] "x30_34_ft_opp_fg_pct"      "x35_39_ft_opp_fgm"        
#> [25] "x35_39_ft_opp_fga"         "x35_39_ft_opp_fg_pct"     
#> [27] "x40_ft_opp_fgm"            "x40_ft_opp_fga"           
#> [29] "x40_ft_opp_fg_pct"


# make each list in a `rowSet` a named list, 
# this allows us to use dplyr::bind_rows() to create a tibble
json$resultSets$rowSet |>
  lapply(setNames, clean_names) |>
  dplyr::bind_rows()
```

Result:

```r
#> # A tibble: 30 × 29
#>       team_id team_name            less_than_5_ft_opp_fgm less_than_5_ft_opp_fga
#>         <int> <chr>                                 <dbl>                  <dbl>
#>  1 1610612737 Atlanta Hawks                          22                     33.6
#>  2 1610612738 Boston Celtics                         17.4                   28.5
#>  3 1610612751 Brooklyn Nets                          17.9                   28.8
#>  4 1610612766 Charlotte Hornets                      20.5                   31.8
#>  5 1610612741 Chicago Bulls                          18                     28.5
#>  6 1610612739 Cleveland Cavaliers                    17.2                   28.8
#>  7 1610612742 Dallas Mavericks                       20                     29.5
#>  8 1610612743 Denver Nuggets                         18.8                   30.3
#>  9 1610612765 Detroit Pistons                        20.5                   32  
#> 10 1610612744 Golden State Warrio…                   17                     25.8
#> # ℹ 20 more rows
#> # ℹ 25 more variables: less_than_5_ft_opp_fg_pct <dbl>, x5_9_ft_opp_fgm <dbl>,
#> #   x5_9_ft_opp_fga <dbl>, x5_9_ft_opp_fg_pct <dbl>, x10_14_ft_opp_fgm <dbl>,
#> #   x10_14_ft_opp_fga <dbl>, x10_14_ft_opp_fg_pct <dbl>,
#> #   x15_19_ft_opp_fgm <dbl>, x15_19_ft_opp_fga <dbl>,
#> #   x15_19_ft_opp_fg_pct <dbl>, x20_24_ft_opp_fgm <dbl>,
#> #   x20_24_ft_opp_fga <dbl>, x20_24_ft_opp_fg_pct <dbl>, …
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you this is perfect! Sorry one follow up question, how did you obtain the req_url part? Because I am also trying to scrape the following page https://www.nba.com/stats/players/shooting?DistanceRange=By+Zone

I tried replacing "leaguedashteamshotlocations" in your link with "leaguedashplayershotlocations" but it scrapes this page instead https://www.nba.com/stats/players/opponent-shooting?DistanceRange=By+Zone presumably because opponent is still within the url but I have tried replacing it with "player" but that caused a 500 error

Comment: Through network tab of browser's dev tools, browsing through previous rvest + javascript answers should give more insights of this. Couple of mine with few screenshots - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76538104/646761 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/72744066/646761 .

Comment: The URL you are looking for in this particular case is `https://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashplayershotlocations?College=&Conference=&Country=&DateFrom=&DateTo=&DistanceRange=By%20Zone&Division=&DraftPick=&DraftYear=&GameScope=&GameSegment=&Height=&ISTRound=&LastNGames=0&Location=&MeasureType=Base&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PORound=0&PaceAdjust=N&PerMode=PerGame&Period=0&PlayerExperience=&PlayerPosition=&PlusMinus=N&Rank=N&Season=2023-24&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular%20Season&ShotClockRange=&StarterBench=&TeamID=0&VsConference=&VsDivision=&Weight=`

Comment: Again thank you so much for providing that and resources to help me learn. Really appreciate it!